# PHP - Get Input from multiple Range Inputs with POST and a foreach loops

Tags: php

I am iterating through a php array using a foreach loop to post a list of range inputs.

```
foreach ($question_array as $a)
{
    $inputName = $a->name;
    print_r('<form action="" method="post">');
    print_r("<input type='range' name=$inputName ...>");
    prin_r('</form>');
}
```

Once the user answers all the questions, they will press a submit button at the bottom of the page, which triggers a re-iteration to retrieve the inputs

```
foreach ($question_array as $a)
{
    $questionName = $a->name;
    $response = $_POST[$questionName];
    print_r("<p>Question $questionName = $response</p>");
}
```

When the user submits, there is a list of the questions with blanks for the responses

```
q1 = 
q2 =
etc
```

I have successfully passed a string variable as the input name and argument for $_POST for a single input, so I am confident that isn't my problem.

Also, the correct strings are going into the $questionName variable in the print_r statements, so I don't think that is causing a problem either.

Any idea what my issue might be?

Comment: Your problem is in many useless `<form>` tags.

Comment: put the form tags outside the loop

Comment: THIS WORKED! Thank you! I have been stuck on this issue for a long time

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that in each iteration of my first loop, I was putting a new form tag.

THIS IS WRONG:

```
foreach(...)
{
    print_r('<form ...>');
    ...
    print_r('</form>');
}
```

THIS IS CORRECT

```
print_r('<form ...>');
foreach(...)
{
    ...
}
print_r('<input name="submit"...>');
print_r('</form>');
```

When encapsulated the entire posting loop AND the submit button in a single form tag, my responses posted correctly.

Thank you to @u_mulder and @Mihai for answering this question